# Image Processing in an Android Application using RGB

Tags: android, image, processing, rgb

I'll be creating an Android Application that determines the freshness of meat using it's RGB. The flow of the application would be:

1. Capture an image
2. Determine the freshness by clicking one button
3. Displaying the result based from it's RGB.

I have a problem in the RGB part. Hope somebody can help me with this matter.

Comment: What is the problem? Do you have a question related to how to code this - and do you have some code that you have tried?

Comment: I have a problem on how to code this. I can't find anything that is related to RGB

Comment: http://processing.org/reference/red_.html
http://processing.org/reference/green_.html
http://processing.org/reference/blue_.html

Comment: Are you using processing? Or did you mistag?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Processing this could be useful.

Use Processing to scan an image pixel by pixel, so they could be compare to find pattern's in the image.

```
PImage sample;

void setup() {
  size(300,300);
  sample = loadImage("sample.jpg");

  sample.loadPixels();
  image(sample,0,0,300,300);
}

void draw() {    
  //Loop to scan the image pixel by pixel
  for (int x=0; x < sample.width; x++){
    for (int y=0; y < sample.height; y++){

      int location = x + (y * sample.width);
      // Whit the location you can get the current color
      color currentColor = sample.pixels[loc];
      //Do something

    }
  }
}
```